# (R language) how to search and record some rows if I have an index file?

Tags: r

I have an index file, say a list. I name it "t". I also have a table, named "b".

I want to search and record all the rows if the index coincides with the first entry of an row in b. I made this code but it doesn't work.

```
table <- function(t,b){
    for (i in 1:length(t)) {
        if (t[i] %in% b[1,]) {
            for (j in 1:length(b)) {
                if (t[i] ==b[1,j]) {
                    z[i] = c(b[,j])
                         }
                    }
                     }
                    return z
                      }
}
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Please share a small example of `t` and `b`.

Comment: Just as a side note: watch out with naming your function table, because there is a standard-function named table allready.

Comment: tank u for the table advice, an example of t would be c(1,5,6,4,12) y b would be cbind((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)

tank u for helpling

Comment: rows_to_select <- which(b$Var1 %in% t) will give you the rowindices of all rows, where Var1 is present in t. Not sure if this is what you whant to archiev :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i made it by my self i let u the code down. itegral(sec(q))dq to everyone! see u

```
 autoserch <- function(x,y){
znames <- names(y)
x<-as.matrix(x)
y<-as.matrix(y)
m <- length(y[1,])
n <-length(x[,1])
z <- matrix(0,n,m)    
for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (isTRUE(x[i,1] %in% y[,1])) {
        for(j in 1:length(y[,1])){
            if(isTRUE(x[i,1]==y[j,1])){
                z[i,] <- y[j,] 
                         }
                    }
                       }    
             }   
colnames(z)<-znames
print(z)
write.csv(z, file = "consulta_solicitada.csv")
}
```